# Не получается связать объекты и таблицы используя Hibernate java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Уперся и все. Не могу найти ошибки.

есть следующий скрипт создания таблиц:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS message;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS subscriber;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Person (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR,
    role VARCHAR(10)
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    person_id INTEGER REFERENCES person(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    header VARCHAR,
    text VARCHAR,
    path_image VARCHAR UNIQUE,
    date_time TIMESTAMP
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subscriber (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    subscriber_person_id INTEGER REFERENCES person(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    person_id INTEGER REFERENCES person(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    is_friend BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    sender INTEGER REFERENCES person(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    recipient INTEGER REFERENCES person(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    date_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    text VARCHAR
);
```

также есть 4 модели:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
            
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
            
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
            
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
            
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
            
@Column(name = "role")
private String role;
            
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
private List<Post> posts;
            
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "subscriber")
private List<Subscriber> subscribers;
            
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "message")
private List<Message> messages;
}
        
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
    
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
            
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Person person;
            
@Column(name = "header")
private String header;
            
@Column(name = "text")
private String text;
            
@Column(name = "path_image")
private String pathImage;
            
@Column(name = "date_time")
private LocalDateTime dateTime;
}
    
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscriber")
public class Subscriber {
    
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
    
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_person_id")
private Person subscriber;
    
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Person person;
    
@Column(name = "is_friend")
private boolean isFriend;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sender")
private Person sender;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "recipient")
private Person recipient;

@Column(name = "date_time")
private LocalDateTime dateTime;

@Column(name = "text")
private String text;
}
```

У каждой модели есть публичные пустые конструкторы, все геторы и сетеры и конструкторы со всеми параметрами.

При сборке проекта выдает следующее:
rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Collection 'ru.danilov.socialmedia.models.Person.messages' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'message' which does not exist in the target entity 'ru.danilov.socialmedia.models.Message'

В чем у меня проблема?

Comment: я так подозреваю что в `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "message")` имя поля для маппинга на класс Message надо поменять на `sender` или `recipient`

Comment: все правильно, тупо глаза замылило. Спасибо большое!!!!

Answer (score 1):

в @OneToMany(mappedBy = "message") надо указать sender(